# How was Earth able to launch Friendship One so soon after World War Three?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Friendship One was launched in 2067, but how could it have been done four years after WW3 even with Vulcan help?

Comment: Because it was largely based on the design of the Phoenix; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Friendship_1

Comment: 24 years after WWII, man landed on the moon, due largely in part to WWII (and the impending WWIII).... That was 66 years after the first powered flight. - *Life moves pretty fast. If you don't stop and look around once in a while, you could miss it.*

Comment: Well, in Hearts & Minds Friendship One is described as being launched from New York City-but NYC was destroyed in WW3, it just seems unlikely they could have launched anything there so soon.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer:

In my opinion Earth may have had sufficient time to recover from the Third World War by the time Friendship One was launched.

Long Answer:

Actually 2067 is 14 years after 2053.

In *Star Trek: First Contact* the Enterprise E follows a Borg ship back in time at Earth:

> PICARD: Report.
>
> RIKER: Shields are down. Long-range sensors are off-line. Main power's holding.
>
> DATA: According to our astrometric readings we're in the mid twenty-first century. From the radioactive isotopes in the atmosphere I would estimate we have arrived approximately ten years after the Third World War.
>
> RIKER: Makes sense. Most of the major cities have been destroyed. There are few governments left. Six hundred million dead. No resistance.
>
> WORF: Captain!
>
> (the Borg sphere is firing at the surface)
>
> PICARD: Mister Worf. Quantum torpedoes.
>
> WORF: Ready, sir.
>
> PICARD: Fire.
>
> (the Borg sphere explodes)
>
> PICARD: They were firing at the surface. Location?
>
> > RIKER: Western hemisphere, ...North American continent. At a missile complex in central Montana.
>
> PICARD: A missile complex? ...The date? Mister Data, I need to know the exact date.
>
> DATA: April fourth, two thousand sixty-three.
>
> PICARD: April fourth?
>
> RIKER: The day before First Contact.
>
> DATA: Precisely.

So April 4th, 2063 in the calendar used in *Star Trek: First Contact* was approximately ten years after the Third World War, which thus happened about 2053 in the calendar used in *Star Trek: First Contact*.

In the *Voyager* episode "Friendship One" the crew are briefed on the unmanned probe Friendship One:

> PROBE [OC]: We, the people of Earth, greet you in the spirit of peace and humility. As we venture out of our solar system, we hope to earn the trust and friendship of other worlds.
>
> KIM: Friendship One. I had to memorise that recording in third grade.
>
> PARIS: Me, too. I even built a model of the probe.
>
> JANEWAY: Then this should look familiar. It was launched in 2067.
>
> PARIS: Just four years after Zefram Cochrane tested his first warp engine.
>
> NEELIX: What was it designed to do?
>
> CHAKOTAY: Reach out to other species. Pave the way for all the manned missions that would follow.

So Friendship One was launched in the year 2067 in the calendar used in the *Voyager* episode "Friendship One", and 2067 is said to have been four years after Zefrem Cochrane tested his first warp engine, which should have been in 2063, which is the date of the warp engine test flight according to the calendar used in *Star Trek: First Contact*.  So the same calendar seems to be used in *Star Trek: First Contact* and in  in the *Voyager* episode "Friendship One".

In that calendar Friendship  One was launched in 2067, four years after the first warp flight and after contact with the Vulcans, which in turn was approximately ten years after the Third World War in approximately 2053.  Thus Earth has had about fourteen years to recover from the Third World War, the last four of them with Vulcan help, by the time that Friendship One was launched.

I note that in Earth history, the USSR launched Sputnik One, the first artificial Earth satellite, in 1957, which was only twelve years after the end of the devastating World War Two, without any help or advice from more advanced alien civilizations.

Comment: And USSR was poorer and less advanced than the USA before WWII -- which was part of why Sputnik was such a shock to much of the world.

Comment: True but most of the world's cities had been destroyed, hundreds of millions of lives were lost, & much of the world was still in anarchy at least until the end of the 21st century. There couldn't realistically have been an international space agency run through the UN (or its successor) in 2067, could there? Even if there was, San Francisco would have been a more suitable launch point.